# How to add EmguCV controls on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv

I'm trying to use EmguCV with WPF. I added the controls on the windows form
[image: Toolbox]

General:

- Pointer
- HistogramBox
- ImageBox
- MatrixBox
- PanAndZoomPicture...

But these controls don't appear on WPF.

Is there any way of enabling these controls on WPF?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you tried creating them through XAML/code-behind?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange When I try to add the *.dll I get the following error: http://s13.postimg.org/t8w2owncn/error.png

Comment: Can you add a reference to the project? If so, try to see if you can create them in XAML. It's probably because the controls are made for `WinForms` and not `WPF`.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Yes I can add the references, but no, I cannot create those controls in xaml .. they don't appear =\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/ec0d4663-4383-06f5-f0a4-deb44e42fafb.htm), you can see that these user controls are designed for Winforms and not WPF. However, you can host a Winforms control in WPF using a [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx). Follow [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx) for a walkthrough on how to use the WindowsFormHost.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i found a good documentation that really helped me out click on the link https://www.programmersought.com/article/17931213387/
you just need to include a couple of namespaces

```
xmlns:WinFormHost="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"
xmlns:WinFormControls="clr-namespace:Emgu.CV.UI;assembly=Emgu.CV.UI"
```